# company computer was shut down before personal files were saved

Tags: windows-7, networking, login

I'm leaving my company as part of a staff reduction move. I was telecommuting from across the country using company VPN and Outlook server. My Windows 7 Enterprise Dell Latitude stopped working 24 hours before my last day, in what I assume was a defensive move to avoid issues with network access. Because the computer shut down earlier than advertised, I hadn't removed files with PI.

Now, when I attempt to log on, I get an error PXE-E61 Media Test Failure, and PXE-M0F.  I'm prompted to enter a Bit Locker recovery key to get to the log-on screen. Once the recovery key is entered, I see a normal 'Starting Windows' Logon screen with normal sound. Logon process seems normal, but credentials are not accepted, and I get a message that says 'there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request.' This message appears regardless of user info entered (Mickey\Mouse returns the same).

I am also unable to logon to the computer without network via computername\user. The Administrator account is not active either. 
I don't want to go to extremes to logon as my separation from company is amicable, but I do want the files.

Does this sound like a normal administrative technique for locking out an old user, or a coincidence of timing and a real issue flagged by the PXE-E61 message?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic explains this is off-topic: _What topics can I ask about here?_ Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question...  and it is not about … issues specific to corporate IT support and networks...

Comment: Sorry to hear about this, but the reality is we cannot help you. The company decided to shut “your machine” down because that machine was never yours; it was theirs. Don’t take this personally in any way but the only real solution is to contact that company’s IT department and see if they can help you. If they are nice they *might* help you get your specific files. But legally, they have no reason to do so. That is just the reality of a situation like this.

Comment: Your comment is roughly the same suggestion in my comment that you downvoted. Since the separation was amicable, I did suggest it was worth a try

Comment: If the files you need are on the computer, itself, and you're unable to logon to your user, you could try booting a Linux live session to access the drive and recover your files.  Anything on the company servers is generally considered company property.  Is the computer your own or was that provided by the company?